# (C++) Division of a negative double with a positive integer gives me positive result

Tags: c++, math, division, mbed, nucleo

I was assigned to do a small project in a programming class using NUCLEO F401RE development board. I chose to program using Mbed studio, as I think it is easier than programming on STM32 Cude IDE. However, I encountered a problem that some time when I divide negative floating point number with a positive integer, the result turned out to be positive. I decided to write a program to test the said division.

```
#include "mbed.h"

// main() runs in its own thread in the OS
int main()
{
    int i = 1;
    while (true) {
        printf("Divided by %d : %f\n",i,-21.837046/i++);
    }
}
```

Here is the result for the first 40 iteration

```
Divided by 1 : -21.837047
Divided by 2 : -10.918524
Divided by 3 : -7.279016
Divided by 4 : -5.459262
Divided by 5 : -4.367410
Divided by 6 : -3.639508
Divided by 7 : -3.119579
Divided by 8 : -2.729631
Divided by 9 : -2.426339
Divided by 10 : -2.183705
Divided by 11 : -1.985187
Divided by 12 : -1.819754
Divided by 13 : -1.679773
Divided by 14 : -1.559790
Divided by 15 : -1.455804
Divided by 16 : -1.364816
Divided by 17 : -1.284533
Divided by 18 : -1.213170
Divided by 19 : -1.149319
Divided by 20 : -1.091853
Divided by 21 : -1.039860
Divided by 22 : 0.992594
Divided by 23 : 0.949437
Divided by 24 : 0.909877
Divided by 25 : 0.873482
Divided by 26 : 0.839887
Divided by 27 : 0.808780
Divided by 28 : 0.779895
Divided by 29 : 0.753002
Divided by 30 : 0.727902
Divided by 31 : 0.704421
Divided by 32 : 0.682408
Divided by 33 : 0.661729
Divided by 34 : 0.642267
Divided by 35 : 0.623916
Divided by 36 : 0.606585
Divided by 37 : 0.590191
Divided by 38 : 0.574660
Divided by 39 : 0.559925
Divided by 40 : 0.545927
```

Notice that from i = 1 to i = 21 the results were negative as expected, but when i >= 22 the results were positive numbers. Interstingly, when I changed the numerator to a different number such as -30, the results transitioned from negative to positive at i >= 31. Different numerators have different values of i in which the results transition.

```
Divided by 1 : -30.000000
Divided by 2 : -15.000000
Divided by 3 : -10.000000
Divided by 4 : -7.500001
Divided by 5 : -6.000000
Divided by 6 : -5.000000
Divided by 7 : -4.285715
Divided by 8 : -3.750001
Divided by 9 : -3.333334
Divided by 10 : -3.000000
Divided by 11 : -2.727273
Divided by 12 : -2.500001
Divided by 13 : -2.307693
Divided by 14 : -2.142858
Divided by 15 : -2.000000
Divided by 16 : -1.875001
Divided by 17 : -1.764706
Divided by 18 : -1.666667
Divided by 19 : -1.578948
Divided by 20 : -1.500001
Divided by 21 : -1.428572
Divided by 22 : -1.363637
Divided by 23 : -1.304348
Divided by 24 : -1.250001
Divided by 25 : -1.200000
Divided by 26 : -1.153847
Divided by 27 : -1.111112
Divided by 28 : -1.071429
Divided by 29 : -1.034483
Divided by 30 : -1.000000
Divided by 31 : 0.967742
Divided by 32 : 0.937501
Divided by 33 : 0.909091
Divided by 34 : 0.882353
Divided by 35 : 0.857143
Divided by 36 : 0.833334
Divided by 37 : 0.810811
Divided by 38 : 0.789474
Divided by 39 : 0.769231
Divided by 40 : 0.750001
```

Comment: What does `printf("edot:%f\n,edot");` ***really*** print? I suspect you misplaced that closing double-quote and your problem is due to this typo (a typo leading to *undefined behavior*).

Comment: Your code is implausible in at least this line `printf("edot:%f\n,edot");`. A [mre] for your problem would be hardly more than `printf("test:%f\n",-21.837046/2075);`.  Please provide a MRE to demonstrate (only) your problem.

Comment: A positive number from `printf("test:%f\n",-21.837046/2075);` is not to be expected in C++. I doubt just any C++ programmer could solve that based on code only. I suspect that there is something weird going on with the hardware or the compiler.

Comment: Then try `printf("test:%f\n",-21.837046f/2075);` please.

Comment: Not sure what is wrong with your compiler, but maybe the issue is that this is double and you printf it as float.

Comment: @eerorika The shown code is weird enough and if it is actually the code which causes the described misbehaviour I'd look for a promising UB-line and be done. No need to blame poor compiler and hardware. I hope that the shown code is not what OP really uses..... that is why I asked for a more surgically [mre].

Comment: @Yunnosch Oh yea, anything could be UB.

Comment: I fail to see how that entire novel in code is relevant to a single printf that's the subject of the question. Putting just that printf by itself, in `main()` of its own, produces the expected results, a negative number. Cannot reproduce.

Comment: @eerorika I did not simplify that much. I agree with "UB can cause anything", for that you'd need to identify the code which causes the UB. Which in the shown code is not that hard....

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Ahhh.. sorry about that, it was my mistake when I was editing my code in the question. In my actual code I got it correct, but the result is as described, it was always a negative number.

Comment: @Yunnosch Yes I did not use that in my actual code. I made the mistake when I typed the code on this thread. The result was negative number as I described. Interestingly when I tried some simple division such as printf("test:%f\n",-5.0/2); it did give me a correct result (-2.5).

Comment: I am going to correct my typo so that it is not the focus of this question. Again, sorry about that. But the typo was not the cause of the problem as I got that line on my actual code correct.

Comment: "made the mistake when I typed the code" Yes, that is an often observed mistake. You are not the only one... That is however why the concept of the [mre] is so highly valuated here. Please try to apply it as strictly as you can. For that you need to follow the link, read everything there and for each desribed detail ask yourself "Can I do that more strictly as described than I already did?"

Comment: By the way as long as the shown code gives the impression of being a non-[mre], you probably have to expect that the question stays closed. Providing a real MRE on the other hand probably gets it reopened.

Comment: @Yunnosch I have rewritten my question. Hopefully it is concise now. Sorry again.

Comment: Good work. You have my reopen vote.

Comment: Have you noticed that in both examples the sign switch happens when the result goes above -1? Looks like a compiler bug to me, introducing some wrong optimization. Can you check which optimization flag you are passing to the compiler, if any? Also, if you could ask the compiler to generate the assembly and add it to the question, it would probably help. That said, I'll leave it to the experts.

Comment: Please double check the includes. I'd expect another include to support `printf()`. Does the "mbed.h" cover that?

Comment: @Yunnosch Inside the "mbed.h" I can only see the #include of many other header files. However, I was following this official documentation: https://os.mbed.com/docs/mbed-os/v6.3/debug-test/debugging-using-printf-statements.html so I am pretty sure that "mbed.h" covers printf.

Comment: @FabiosaysReinstateMonica I have just noticed that. Thank you for pointing that out. But may I ask what is an optimization flag? For me the hardest things about programming are these computer terms. My experience of programming only involved working with no more than 4-6 files, and when I have to move to a more complicate programming environment I feel completely lost. For example, the Mbed studio that I am using now have thousands if not millions of files in a single project. The documentation is also filled with terms that I have no idea what they mean. I simply don't know where to start!

Comment: I understand. However, using `printf()` without the proper include can behave weirdly and does NOT guarantee to get a helpful compiler error/warning. If no other answer arrives I recommend to invest effort on double checking this.

Comment: @YongyuthaKunapinun Given the same source code, compilers can produce different binaries. Normally, if you let the compiler do more work, and analyze the code more, the compilation will take longer, but the resulting binary should run faster. Using GCC (the compiler used under Linux) you would choose this by [adding "-O2" (or others) to the command line](https://www.rapidtables.com/code/linux/gcc/gcc-o.html#optimization) that launches the compilation. Do you know what compiler you are using? Do you compile from a command line or from your IDE?

Comment: @FabiosaysReinstateMonica I wrote and compiled my code using the Mbed Studio IDE.

Comment: The new code you show have another problem: There's no defined evaluation order between function arguments, which means it's unknown if the argument `i` or `-21.837046/i++` is evaluated first. This leads to *undefined behavior* as you modify `i` in the second expression.

Comment: @FabiosaysReinstateMonica It is written in this documentation :https://os.mbed.com/docs/mbed-os/v6.2/program-setup/build-profiles-and-rules.html that I can change the optimization flag using .json file. I managed to reduce the optimization level to -O0 but that didn't help and the IDE was kind of buggy when I tried to do that. Anyway, I appreciate your kindness for explaining me what an optimization flag is, atleast I learn something new today.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thank you. That's interesting. I never think about the evaluation order between arguments. I always thought that the evaluation between arguments is done from left to right, now I am not sure about that. However, I don't think that will affect the sign of division's result as i stays positive.

Comment: Add `-Wunsequenced` (clang++) or `-Wsequence-point` (g++) to catch stuff like that. Add `-Wall -Wextra -Werror` too.  Undefined behavior is ... undefined, so it can have an effect on _everything_ in your program. Replace your `main()` with `int main() { for(int i = 1; i <= 40; ++i) { printf("Divided by %d : %f\n", i, -21.837046 / i); } }` - Do you still get the same problem?